# Why the DELIMITER $$ in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, delimiter

Why do we need to use DELIMITER `$$` in pl/pgsql? Is this important like terminator in other programming languages (eg. semicolon ";" in PHP)?

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL? (PL/SQL is Oracle server's procedure language and doesn't use `DELIMITER`)

Comment: we can use in oracle but it is not mandatory.Thanks  Mat

Comment: `DELIMITER` isn't a keyword in Oracle. Where did you see that you can use it?

Comment: i am not export in oracle but i can DELIMITER is also valid in oracle.